# Should a table with only 1 field of useful data be its own table

Tags: database, database-design

Just got a question here about a database table. If the table only has a primary key (identity) and 1 column of useful data, is it okay to be its own table or should it be in the parent table as just the data?

The table is storing Security Questions that the user will set up with they make their account and be used to reset password in the event they want to change password or forgot the password. I have the ID of the question, and the question string in this table.

The reason I have it in its own table is that the same question could be used for many users so why store the question many times in the parent table. Thats my thinking, just wanted a few others' opinions on this.

EDIT: The Security Questions are going to be input by my team, not the user themselves. The user will pick one of the questions to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest this sample design using bridge table:
[image]

You can have multiple questions for a user as well as their answers unique. Also, the questions can be same for multiple users.

Comment: I like your thinking with separating that out from the User table. But, if we are only using 1 question/answer set per user, would separating that UserQuestions table out from users table be beneficial in any way?

Comment: @Andy Link: In that case, you should go for **one to one** relationship. The Question table should be separated because multiple users can have same questions and they will be choosing from the list of questions. Just add the reference key from Users table to Questions table.

Comment: Okay so by that logic should I then do the same idea for all the State Abbreviations that are used in several of my tables inside the database?

Answer (score 0):

You must always try to prevent duplicates, that's why your solution is the best.
it will also keep your database smaller. A foreign key with int value is smaller than a string.